# Why do notification types have a name?

Tags: lightning-experience, visual-workflow, notification

I'm asking about the "bell icon" notifications here.

This [Getting your users attention with Custom Notifications](https://andyinthecloud.com/2019/06/30/getting-your-users-attention-with-custom-notifications/) article illustrates the UI where you have to add a custom notification type before being able to send one through a flow or through the REST API:

[image: adding a notification type]

It seems like there are only 3 useful variations here:

- Desktop and Mobile
- Desktop only
- Mobile only

and I haven't seen anywhere that the name or API name are surfaced. (Yes, the name can be seen in the flow editor but acting more like a comment than something active that carries significance when the notification is sent.)

In some work we are doing right now, we could just create one notification type and route everything through that. Or is there some intended (future?) purpose for the naming and the need to pass the notification type Id value meaning we should create several?

Comment: Perhaps it would be helpful when debugging / looking into how much you're using one type of notification over the other. Not sure where you would find that level of detail though (debug logs, etc)

Comment: Thanks Brian. Getting hold of the Id directly in Apex requires a tooling API call which is awkward so I'm looking to see if it's worth the trouble to create many of these types. Not convinced so far that it is...

Comment: My guess it is because there are "Supported Channels" options that we can specify what channels to receive the notification from for different use case.

For critical type of notification, eg. order processing failed, probably Order Desk users to be notified as soon as possible, so the notification will be sent to them via both Desktop and Mobile. 
For something non-critical, eg. notifying users of upcoming production maintenance, probably is more suitable via desktop.